# Using C++/CLI dll when generate serialization assembly is enabled

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli, interop

I have a C++/CLI dll wrapping some native C++ code which I want to use in a C# project.

Everything works fine if the `Generate serialization assembly` property is set to `Auto` or `Off`. However, when I set this property to `On` I get the following error: `SGEN : error : An attempt was made to load an assembly with an incorrect format: example.dll`

Any solution for this that doesn't require disabling the serialization assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C++/CLI assembly contains unmanaged code, it can only be loaded by a program that runs with the same target architecture.  SGen loads it to get access to the metadata.  There are two versions of SGen.exe, a 32-bit and a 64-bit version.

So this falls over with this error if the 32-bit version of SGen tries to load the x64 build of your C++/CLI assembly.  Or the other way around.  You can diagnose it by looking at the detailed MSBuild trace and taking notice of the sgen.exe path.  Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity = Detailed.  The 32-bit version of sgen.exe lives in the "NETFX 4.x Tools" directory, the 64-bit version in "NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64" directory.

Classic way you'll get the wrong bitness of the tool is when you haven't configured your C# project to be compatible with the target architecture of your C++/CLI project.  Right-click it > Properties > Build tab > Platform target setting.  Make it match with your C++/CLI project target.  If you pick x86 or AnyCPU then you get the 32-bit version of SGen, x64 begets the 64-bit version of SGen.

Comment: Thanks, I just solved it. The problem was not a mismatch between the architecture of SGen and my application as you suggested, but your answer pointed me in the right direction. The C++/CLI assembly needs a number of 3rdparty assemblies which I had next to my application's .exe. I only needed to put them in the PATH system variable so they can be found by SGen.

Comment: Hmm, that generates a different exception.  Well, as long as it works I guess.

Comment: By running SGen.exe from a command promt it also showed `Could not load file or assembly example.dll or one of its dependencies.` which is the error I usually get when the dependencies are not found.

Comment: Yes, that's the exception you'd get, not the BadImageFormatException you asked about in your question.  I suppose two things could be wrong :)